# Result of user-defined function not displaying on web app

Tags: output, user-defined-functions, streamlit

I am trying to define a function that divides Amount of money by Number of days.
So far the user can submit values, but I don't know how to make the result display on my Streamlit web app.
I copied part of my code below.
P.S. I am also a complete beginner in Python.
Thanks for any help

```
#HOW OFTEN EAT OUT
st.write("2. How often do you eat out?") 
form04 = st.form(key='form04')
days = form04.text_input('Please enter average number of days')
submit04 = form04.form_submit_button('Submit')
#HOW MUCH INCOME
if submit04:
  st.write('3. What is your monthly income?') 
  form05 = st.form(key='form05')
  income = form05.text_input('Please enter monthly income')
  submit05 = form05.form_submit_button('Submit')  
  if submit05:
      def idealbudget(days, income):
          budget=float(income)/float(days)
          return float(budget)
          st.write('Result is', budget)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet, you define a function but you never actually call it:

```
  if submit05:
      def idealbudget(days, income):
          budget=float(income)/float(days)
          return float(budget)
          st.write('Result is', budget)
```

Additionally, your `st.write` call is tabbed incorrectly, it should be at the same level as the `def` statement. A working solution probably looks like the following (untested):

```
  if submit05:
      def idealbudget(days, income):
          budget=float(income)/float(days)
          return float(budget)

      st.write('Result is', idealbudget(days, income))
```